# MS Access Deployment

Tags: ms-access

I plan to package and deploy an ms access .accdb that I've created in access 2016 using SSE Setup to a user that has a full version of access 2003. If the package installs Access 2016 runtime, will it corrupt the 2003 software, or will it only affect the accdb that I am packaging

Comment: I previously answered that this should be okay, but I have deleted that answer because I think my experiences were with older versions that didn’t share as many components. I still think it should work but I can’t say for certain

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea, [installing different versions of Office components](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Install-and-use-different-versions-of-Office-on-the-same-PC-6ebb44ce-18a3-43f9-a187-b78c513788bf?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) at the same time. Deploy a Access 2003 version or force user to upgrade or using a virtual machine.

Comment: I went ahead and deployed and had it and set the minimum prerequisites to access 2007. The install allowed the user to install access 2007 Runtime.

Comment: Sorry about that, I pressed enter before I was done with the comment. It's working fine, but if the user want's to open an .mdb created in access 2003, they have to use the 'Open With" option and select the 2003 version. It then goes thru a switching process after which all access use 2003 by default. To switch back to the runtime, they have to 'Open With' 2007.....It's not an ideal setup, but it's only temporary until the user upgrades his equipment. Thank you both for your help